# How can I add a If Else End If to this query

Tags: mysql, sql

The following queries returns NULL when no value is found. How can I add a `If` around the two of them separately so If its `Null` then `Not Found` else return the query's result?

```
SET @id = 26;
SELECT 
(SELECT id  FROM devTable WHERE id <= @id AND country = 'US' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9,1) AS `prev`,
(SELECT id  FROM devTable WHERE id >= @id AND country = 'US' ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT 1,1) AS `next`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```
SET @id = 26;
SELECT 
IFNULL(
  (SELECT id FROM devTable WHERE id <= @id AND country = 'US' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 9,1),
  'Not Found') AS prev,
IFNULL(
  (SELECT id FROM devTable WHERE id >= @id AND country = 'US' ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT 1,1),
  'Not Found') AS next
```

Answer (score -1):

Look up the T-SQL Exists command.

Like:

```
IF EXISTS( SELECT STUFF FROM JUNK WHERE ITEMS=5) THEN
BEGIN
SELECT "HAVE JUNK"  -- OR PRINT, SET, ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT "SORRY, DON'T HAVE JUNK" -- OR PRINT, SET, ...
END
END
```

Comment: TSQL? This question is tagged `mysql`, *not* `sql-server`